# calculate column of related model while in pagination

Tags: laravel-5

I have a model named `Invoice` which is has relation of `hasMany` to `InvoiceItems`. in `InvoiceItems` there is a field/column named `total`. how do I calculate that field when dealing with pagination? here is the code

```
$periode = $months_translate[date('n') - 1].'-'.date('Y');

$invoices = Invoice::where('billing_period', $periode)
->orderBy('number')->paginate($per_page);

$total_amount = 0; // this is what i am trying to figure out.
foreach($invoices as $invoice){
    foreach($invoice->items as $item){
        $total_amount += $item->sum('total');
    }
}
```

`$total_amount` is calcuating all records, including outside current `billing_period` scoop, so simply it's give wrong result.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use laravel with method while writing the query.It will get the invoice items of those invoices who satisfy the condition given by you. 
Read this [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

```
$invoices = Invoice::with('InvoiceItems')->where('billing_period', $periode)
                 ->orderBy('number')->paginate($per_page);
```

Comment: I've following your suggestion but the result is still wrong.

Comment: @DarielPratama is your hasMany function name InvoiceItems ? or just items? In that case you need to pass the function name of the relation as an argument to with method.